How to write a tests for PickVisualMediaRequest, in android studio?
I have a fragment in my app that requests the user to upload an image. How can I write a Junit test that runs on the emulated device that would select and image from the pop up? I am also wondering if there is a way to upload an image into the virtual device before my test runs in the test, to ensure that the test runs if the phone doesn't have any photos in the gallery?
I have tried to use UiDevice but I can't figure it out.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Well, I might be somewhere out of point, but I'm working on some similar problem and this is what I've done.
To provide brief description, following code is not exact test of picking image from PickVisualMedia(). But it works almost the same as it should be.
First make ActivityResultRegistry to get Uri and viewModel that will update view.
Then launching it like following can trigger uri as is should be called in ActiovityResultLauncher -> onResult(uri). Then you can call functions to process it and pass it to viewModel.
    // Mock ActivityResultRegistry
    val mockRegistry = object : ActivityResultRegistry() {
        override fun <I : Any?, O : Any?> onLaunch(
            requestCode: Int,
            contract: ActivityResultContract<I, O>,
            input: I,
            options: ActivityOptionsCompat?
        ) {
            val result = Uri.parse("android.resource:///${R.drawable.}")
            dispatchResult(requestCode, result as O)
        }
    }

    val activity = composeTestRule.activity
    val myViewModel = ViewModelProvider(activity).get(myViewModel::class.java)
    val context = activity.applicationContext


    // Register the image picker with the mock registry
    val launcher = mockRegistry.register("key", ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()) { result: Uri? ->
        // Handle the result here
        if (result != null) {
            val byteArray = uriToByteArray(
                context = context,
                uri = result,
            )
            if(byteArray != null){
                myViewModel.setImage(byteArray)
            }
        }
    }
    launcher.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly))

